# portlet session variable not retrieved until after two page refreshes

Tags: jsp, portlet, websphere-portal

In my controller in `serveResource` method I am setting an attribute to the `PortletSession` variable.

```
PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession();
session.removeAttribute("Letters");
session.setAttribute("Letters", "0");
```

I am trying to retrieve that value in the JSP page and somehow I don't get it immediately after I load the page. After refreshing the page again then I get the value.

```
<%=portletSession.getAttribute("Letters") %>
```

Comment: Did you configure any caches (in portlet and/or server)?

Comment: No, I didn't configure any caches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the expected behavior. Usually `serveResource()` method will be invoked as part of an AJAX call. Your whole page doesn't gets refreshed when `serveResource()` method is called. So even if session contains the updated value, you are not able to see the change since the whole portlet JSP is not processed again at the server end.